# Jquery contains both special chars and lowercase

Tags: javascript, jquery, contains

**I have this little script for search text in div :**

**TEST HERE :** https://jsfiddle.net/w87q9fjy/1/

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
jQuery(document).ready(function () 
{
$('#search').click(function(){
   $('.net_container').hide();
   var txt = $('#search-criteria').val().toLowerCase(); 
   $('.net_container:contains("'+txt+'")').show(1000).css("color","red");
});
});
</script>
```

The problem it´s many content have words with uppercase and lowercase letters and i need search with all in lowercase letters, also i need eliminate text with chars as á é í ó ú, for search without problems

```
 var txt = $('#search-criteria').val().toLowerCase();
```

**also put with lowercase :**

```
 $('.net_container:contains("'+txt+'")').show(1000).css("color","red");
```

And finally change special chars in both cases for show words with all letters in lowercase and without special chars as i tell until, i try do this , but i don´t know how i need put for works, it´s the true becasuse i don´t know all about jquery

Thank´s in advanced for the help, best regards

**I TRY THIS CODE FROM OTHER USER BUT I CAN´T WORKS :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
jQuery(document).ready(function () 
{
$('#search').click(function(){
$('.net_container').hide(); 
    /*

   var txt = $('#search-criteria').val().toLowerCase(); 
   $('.net_container:contains("'+txt+'")').show(1000).css("color","red");
   */

var txt = $('#search-criteria').val().toLowerCase();
$('.net_container').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().toLowercase().includes(txt);    
}).show(1000).css("color","red");


});
});
</script>



<input type="text" class="net_search" value="Buscar Título" onclick="this.value=''" id="search-criteria"/>
<input type="button" id="search" value="GO" class="net_search_boton"/>
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what your problem is. What have you tried? What is the problem?

Comment: Simple i want search text in divs with same class , but when search i need transform text in all cases to lowercase and delete special chars

Comment: It's not clear from the title of the question "Jquery contains and special chars and lowecase". What does that mean? The problem to be solved should be in the question title.

Comment: ***Write a title that summarizes the specific problem*** + ***Introduce the problem before you post any code***
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '')` to only accept alphanumeric values. JSFiddle (with your code): http://jsfiddle.net/p9m8wkch/

```js
$('ul li').each(function(){
 var val = $(this).text();
 if(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi.test(val)){
 $(this).css("color", "red");
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>1a</li>
<li>!!s</li>
<li>!%@^#</li>
<li>text ~</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead so you can match cases in callback.

Here's simple case just doing the lowercase. Will leave it to you to replace the special characters

```js
var txt = 'Foo'.toLowerCase();    

$('.net_container').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().toLowerCase().includes(txt);
}).show(1000).css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="net_container">item 1</li>
  <li class="net_container">item 2</li>
  <li class="net_container">FOO BAR</li>
  <li class="net_container">item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I try your code but i can get works, see my post i put the code with your changes

Comment: Create a [mcve] that has real content in it that we can run

Comment: you copied version I had typo for lowerCase and was throwing error. Type "hello" in this one https://jsfiddle.net/w87q9fjy/4/ Not really sure what you want regarding the special characters to be honest

Answer (score 0):

if case if you are facing some problem in `filter` you can use `each` loop though..

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () 
{
  $('#search').click(function(){
 $('.net_container').hide();    
        var txt = $('#search-criteria').val().toLowerCase();
        
        $('.net_container').each(function(){           
          if($(this).text().toLowerCase().includes(txt)) {         
         $(this).show(1000).css("color","red");
          }
       });
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="net_search" value="WORLD" onclick="this.value=''" id="search-criteria"/>
<input type="button" id="search" value="GO" class="net_search_boton"/>


<div class="net_container">
   <span>Hello Cómo estás</span>
</div>


<div class="net_container">
   <span>Cómo estás Hello World</span>
</div>
```